# Создание ветки для обновления

Tags: netbeans

Можно ли как-то, работая в `Netbeans`, когда открыты файлы, чтобы я нажал команду или еще чего и у меня создался архив с данными файлами и при этом, чтобы пути соответствовали и папки тоже.

А то вручную надоедает уже постоянно отбирать файлы и папки, ну или постоянно копировать весь проект и удалять все, кроме того, что исправил.

Потом начинается какая-нибудь путаница и труба начинается.

Ну я все-же полагаю, что я могу просто чего-то не знать.

Comment: Откройте для себя git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил все-же использовать `git`, я думал будет заморочка какая-то, как почитал (просто столько времени не было), но все-же решил попробовать поставить, так я вообще ничего из написанного не делал, так как у меня все автоматом встало и `netbeans` сразу научился делать, добавки, удаления, очистки, экспорт файлов, так как мне собственно нужно было.

Единственный момент, мне нужно было `tar.gz` архивы, использую выражение:

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD | xargs tar -zcf archiveName.tar.gz
```

Все работает прекрасно.
Ребятам огромный плюс, я был не прав =)